# The Characters in excel output file of spoon is not encoded properly

Tags: excel, debugging, encoding, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I have a kettle job that read data from a table and generates excel file. The header/column names are renamed to thai language using rename values. For writing excel file I use TIS-620 encoding. But in generated excel file the header field appears as ?????? . This issue is only for header field and not for the data. I tried using other encoding methods such as UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 etc. But it didn't work. Is this some kind of bug? Because the file is correct in one of the client systems but not in sever and other systems. What would be the reason ? please help..

Comment: Perhaps the file itself is correctly created but excel interprets it poorly?

Comment: I think its not the issue of excel interpretation. When I save .ktb file in my laptop then the generated file is encoded correctly. The issue occurs only when we save the file in repository.